# Custom Symbol Font not displayed in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

The following setup

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SymbolTest</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="greek">μ ω Ω ≥ ⊗ ↔  ± √ ≠ ♦ ♥ ♠ ⇐ ⇒ ⊥ ♦ ⊆ ∅</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Symbol;
  src: url("../fonts/Symbol/symbol.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/Symbol/symbol.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/Symbol/symbol.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/Symbol/symbol.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/Symbol/symbol.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/Symbol/symbol#symbolregularregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
span.greek {
  font-family: Symbol;
}
```

Produces very weird results in Internet Explorer compared to other browsers;

**Crome, Local**

[image: Chrome, Local]

**Chrome, Server**

[image: Chrome, Server]

**FF, Local**

[image: FF, Local]

**FF, Server**

[image: FF, Server]

**IE10, Local**

[image: IE10, Local]

**IE10, Server**

[image: IE10, Server]

**IE11, Local**

Asks me wether I want to allow ActiveX components - Note that in the background, the font used is the default windows Symbol font...

[image: IE11, Local, Before]

After clicking "accept", it changes to

[image: IE11, Local, After]

What is going on here? I created the font using FontSquirrel and used the "*bulletproof*" `@font-face` syntax, but it's still not working as expected...?

Comment: I question your doctype choice. It's been far too long since I've dealt with that type for me to comment on it but I don't think it's appropriate here and I wouldn't expect IE to handle it properly.

Comment: Okay, I will give some other doctypes a try. Thanks for the hint

Comment: As an aside, please don't do this `maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"`...we're not all blessed with perfect eyesight, some of us **need** to scale. It's poor UX all round.

Comment: Well, for new web pages, the only doctype you should use is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @Paulie_D Welcome to the wonderful world of corporate intranet websites... I tried discussing this, but to no avail. "Zooming must not be supported"...

Comment: @Rob I know - I also know there was some good reason I had to use this (see comment to Paulie_D) - But I'll try it...

Comment: You could check character sets; if some of the browsers are not set to use some other charset instead of the one given in the page.

Comment: Well, depends on what how you define "working" - When I don't specify the font, or it cannot be found, the browser will fall back to the default "Symbol" font of windows. It looks the same, mostly, but the one I use has a little different spacing...

Comment: I just tested, and it turns out that the Greek characters by themselves work fine in IE. However, if I specify `font-family:'Symbol'`, I get the very same erroneous result you do. So my conclusion is, IE and Symbol do not work very well together. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLawL1j4/). Find another font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, the issue seems to be resolved. As *Mr Lister* pointed out, IE itself apparently doesn't like when you paste UTF8 symbols and wrap them in the `Symbol` font.

I checked into the Symbol font with a designer colleague and it appears that IE tries to actually use the typed character (e.g. `U+221A` which is `SQUARE ROOT`) and maps it against the used font - `Symbol`.

`Symbol` obviously doesn't have a proper character for the character at code point `8730` - because `Symbol` only supports 255 characters.

This means, IE will display a `?` instead.

The insteresting point here is, that the other browser fall back to the default font and use the UTF8 value of the character and display it properly.

The solution we now use is to not use any font, as the whole publication process is UTF8 anyway, so there is no need to actually use the `Symbol` font anywhere. We just copy all characters as they are, and it works.